# Calculate Lat-Long given tile coordinates in Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am building an image retrieval system where the user selects a tile from the leaflet map (ie. selects a part of the image). Similar tiles belonging to other images from the database are returned. When a result tile is clicked, it redirects to the leaflet map for the image containing the result tile.

Here is a snapshot of the system :

[image]

What I Want to Achieve: To bring the tile (which was clicked on previously) to the centre of the redirected map.

Here is what I have tried so far based on https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tile_numbers_to_lon..2Flat._2
I get xtile, ytile and zoom from the tile url eg tiles/image1/4/3/2.png

```
    //calculating lat,lon of tile centre to make it come in centre after redirection
    n = 2.0 ** zoom
    lon_deg = xtile / n * (360.0 - 180.0)
    lat_rad = Math.atan(Math.sinh(Math.PI * (1 - 2 * ytile / n)))
    lat_deg= lat_rad * (180/Math.PI)
    window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/map.html";
    map.flyTo([lon_deg,lat_deg]);
```

This redirects to coordinates far off the map and I have to drag again to even get to the image. Can somebody guide me on where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: Leaflet expects [lat, lng] order.

Comment: @ghybs I did exactly that before, it redirected to the wrong coordinates. Then I tried reversing. It is wrong in both cases.

Comment: Your post would highly benefit from adding this directly: what you have already tried, what did not work, how you ended up with your current code, etc.

Comment: In your tile URL "4/3/2.png", which one is x, y and z?